# Processing n lines of stdin at a time

Tags: python

I am trying to write a python program that if given input like (no spaces between lines, just a newline character at the end of each line)

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
....
```

through stdin, will create two strings. One will haves lines #1-4, #9-12, #17-20, etc., while the other will have lines #5-8, #13-16, #21-24, etc. Currently I am using sys.stdin.readlines() and then trying to parse 8 lines at a time, but I'm not sure what the most effective way to do this is.

Comment: have you tried `sys.stdin.readlines(n)`?

Comment: I dont know how many lines are in the input file, so how should I iterate through sets of 8 lines?

Comment: Sorry, just realised my code counts `n` characters, not lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enumerate the lines from stdin and use the line count to select which list to target. `count//4` would count up for every 4 lines and then `mod 2` would alternate 0 / 1 per 4 lines. So, put the lists you want into an outer list and you've got your program

```
import sys

l1 = []
l2 = []
lists = [l1, l2]

for i, line in enumerate(sys.stdin):
    lists[(i//4)%2].append(line.strip())

print(l1)
print(l2)
```

Comment: I want the output as Strings not as lists. Could you modify your code to reflect that?

Comment: Never mind, I got it by using '\n\.join(l1). Thanks!